# phpunit for wordpress in docker (inherit from final class)

Tags: wordpress, docker, phpunit

I am writing a wordpressplugin and want to create a phpunit testenvironment for it. For that I've created a docker container using a php:7.2-apache base container and installed phpunit on it via phar archive on the image. After that I have set some environment variables and used the following bashscript, which is similear to the one created by "wp scaffold plugin-tests", as entrypoint.

```
# INSTALL WP-CORE
wp core download --path="${WPPATH}" --allow-root
waitforit -t 60 database:3306 -- wp config create --dbuser="${WPDBUSER}" --dbpass="${WPDBPASS}" --dbname="${WPDBNAME}" --dbhost="${WPDBHOST}" --path="${WPPATH}" --allow-root

wp db create --path="${WPPATH}" --allow-root
wp core install --url="${WPURL}" --title="SpitzeDev" --admin_user="${ADMINUSER}" --admin_password="${ADMINPASS}" --admin_email="${ADMINMAIL}" --path="${WPPATH}" --allow-root
chown www-data:www-data "/var/www/html" -R

# Install WP-Testsuite for PHPUnit
if [ ! -d $WP_TESTS_DIR ]; then
    mkdir -p $WP_TESTS_DIR
    svn co --quiet https://develop.svn.wordpress.org/tags/$(wp core version --allow-root --path=${WPPATH})/tests/phpunit/includes/ $WP_TESTS_DIR/includes
    svn co --quiet https://develop.svn.wordpress.org/tags/$(wp core version --allow-root --path=${WPPATH})/tests/phpunit/data/ $WP_TESTS_DIR/data
fi

# Configure WP-Testuite for PHPUnit
if [ ! -f wp-tests-config.php ]; then
    download https://develop.svn.wordpress.org/${WP_TESTS_TAG}/wp-tests-config-sample.php "$WP_TESTS_DIR"/wp-tests-config.php
    # remove all forward slashes in the end
    WP_CORE_DIR=$(echo ${WPPATH} | sed "s:/\+$::")
    sed -i "s:dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/src/':'${WP_CORE_DIR}/':" "$WP_TESTS_DIR"/wp-tests-config.php
    sed -i "s/youremptytestdbnamehere/$WPDBNAME/" "$WP_TESTS_DIR"/wp-tests-config.php
    sed -i "s/yourusernamehere/$WPDBUSER/" "$WP_TESTS_DIR"/wp-tests-config.php
    sed -i "s/yourpasswordhere/$WPDBPASS/" "$WP_TESTS_DIR"/wp-tests-config.php
    sed -i "s|localhost|${WPDBHOST}|" "$WP_TESTS_DIR"/wp-tests-config.php
fi
phpunit
```

The script works fine until phpunit is called. But then the follwing exception is thrown:

"Fatal error: Class PHPUnit_Util_Test may not inherit from final class (PHPUnit\Util\Test) in /tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/includes/phpunit6-compat.php on line 18"

I don't really understand how this error could occure. If I use this the phpunit tests of my plugin the error is not thrown. If use these Tests on my local maschine they work just fine.

Comment: In PHPUnit 7, the `PHPUnit\Util\Test` class is `final`. Your `PHPUnit_Util_Test` class cannot inherit from it.

Comment: I've seen that and It looks normal to me that this should not work. But its the code for the testing suite, which is officially proposed by the WordPress Codex, which tries to extend the final class.

Now I have changed the container from a debian to alpine linux and now the code does work. I'll think the class, which tries to extend the final class, is not loaded if a certain php-extension is available. (PHP-Version was the same) But I'm not really sure about that. But something seems spooky about that WordPress testing code.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem when trying to test using the wordpress core test framework with phpunit 7.0.3 and PHP 7.1.6

Solved by switching to phpunit 6.1.0 and PHP 7.0.20.

Comment: I have  solved the problem by switching to another baseimage for my container. I'll think this propably solves the problem in the same way.

Comment: @de-loke can you point out the container you used to solve the problem. as I am also stuck in similar condition,

Comment: The entry point of my container executes the following script that solved my problem, the configuration code is missing at the end, because I don't know if I am allowed to publish it because it wasn't written by me: 
https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/22v3
This script is called using:
waitforit -t 60 database:3306 -- Tests/install-testsuite.sh ${WPDBNAME} ${WPDBUSER} ${WPDBPASS} ${WPDBHOST} ${GFACTIVATIONKEY}

To make that work you need a few tools on your conatiner installed: wp-cli, wait-for-it and phpunit itself.

Comment: The Core ticket for that bug is [#43218](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/43218).